# we come across so many noteworthy thoughts *to point out*. What's wrong with this sentence?

Tags: verb-agreement, subjects

I have a feeling that something is wrong with this sentence but don't know it's grammatical reason. Can you help me with it?

In reviewing Sylvia Plath`s short poem Mirror, we come across so many noteworthy thoughts **to point out**, but one of the most eye-catching   facets  one may want to underscore is...

Comment: You can't point to a thought (unless you point to your head I suppose)

Comment: Aren't "point to" and "point out" different from each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly grammatically correct, but is quite clumsy and overwritten.

To give an analagous sentence

> When walking through the forest we find many mushrooms **to collect**, but the tastier ones are...

**Point out** is a verb in your sentence, but there are other verbs that would be better suited - **highlight**, **note** or **emphasise** come to mind.

If I were writing the sentence, here's what I'd write:

**Original**

> In reviewing Sylvia Plath`s short poem Mirror, we come across so many noteworthy thoughts to point out, but one of the most eye-catching facets one may want to underscore is...

**Revision**

> In reviewing Sylvia Plath`s short poem Mirror, we discover many thoughts worth noting. One of the most eye-catching facets is...

**Revisions:**

- 'so many' - 'so' is a redundant word. Don't use it.
- 'come across' - Very informal. Use a synonym.
- 'noteworthy thoughts to point out' -> It's redundant to mention that the thought is both noteworthy and is worth pointing out. If you are already pointing it out, then it suggests that's noteworthy, so you can drop the noteworthy.
- 'but one' - 'but' is not necessary.
- I split the run on sentence into two sentences.
- 'one may wish to underscore' - Unnecessary - we've already said that points are noteworthy.

Answer (score 1):

> In reviewing Sylvia Plath`s short poem Mirror, we come across so many noteworthy thoughts to point out, but one of the most eye-catching facets one may want to underscore is...

The problem for me is not one of grammar. It has to do with the meaning. What are these thoughts that you are pointing out. Are they your thoughts? Are they Plath's thoughts?

You cannot point out your own thoughts in someone else's poem -- you can only have thoughts about someone else's poem.

The sentence does however make sense if you say that Plath wrote her thoughts down when she was writing the poem. Of course all poets do that but we can't usually point to one of the poet's phrases and say 'that is a thought' unless the poet actually wrote, "I think ..."

So it depends whether you see the poem as a series of thoughts that you can point out. Maybe you do.